# 2 X 16GB ECC REG (Kingston) Mixed with 3 X 8GB NON-ECC(Hynix)

Tags: memory

I have a server assembled with 2 X 16GB ECC REG (Kingston). Now I am lucky to find 3 new RAM stick in my house. 3 X 8GB non-ECC. I installed these in my server and it shows 56GB RAM now.

My question: is mixing up ECC and non-ECC and diff memory size and diff brands, can this cause problem? Although I did not get any error after installing and thing seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3):

You lose ECC protection on the whole memory. So, mixing ECC and no-ECC is a bad idea on a server.